# Android iritiate through string for specific letter

Tags: android

I have a string, and I can detect if it has an `#` inside it.

```
    if(title.contains("#")){

        SpannableString WordtoSpan = new SpannableString(title);   

        int idx = title.indexOf("#");
        if (idx >= 0) {
            int wordEnd = title.indexOf(" ", idx);
            if (wordEnd < 0) {
                wordEnd = title.length();
            }
            WordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED),
                        idx,
                        wordEnd,
                        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }           

        holder.txtTitle.setText(WordtoSpan);
    } else {
        holder.txtTitle.setText(title);
    }
```

So now, if the string has an `#` it will color it till the end of the word after it with red. This works perfectly. **But** the problem is, when a string has more than one `#` it will color only the first `#` with it word, not the next or the third etc ..

**ex.** Now:
*Notice it ill color only burger with red*

> I love chicken **#burger** , cuz they are #delicious.

**I want**: *Notice bother burger and delicious are colored.*

> I love chicken **#burger** , cuz they are **#delicious** .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use title.split("#") to get a array of strings which contains #.

Something like:

```
String parts = title.split("#");
for(int i = 0; i<parts.length(); i++){
    //TODO: do something with the string part
    //parts[i], this is a part of the string.
}
```

Comment: Yup I ran through that, but couldn't know how to get it running with me code. can you explain to me more?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Pattern to find and match words that contain hashtags in a given string.

```
String text = "I love chicken #burger, because they are #delicious!";

Pattern HASHTAG_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("#(\\w+|\\W+)");
Matcher mat = HASHTAG_PATTERN.matcher(text);

while (mat.find()) {
  String tag = mat.group(0);

  //String tag will contain the hashtag
  //do operations with the hashtag
}
```