# Android Matcher and Pattern cut up from the link

Tags: android, string

I have a string that contains a link.

**ex.** of the string:

> We love to eat choco, eat one up at http://t.co/9BDZvcx59d.

So If I display this string as it is, it would be the same. But if I use matcher and pattern to detect the link and color it, it will cut it up.

**It'll** be: *Bold is green color.*

> We love to eat choco, eat one up at **http://t.co**.

```
    Pattern urlPattern = Patterns.WEB_URL;

      Matcher m = urlPattern.matcher(sb.toString());
        sb = new StringBuffer(sb.length());

        while (m.find()) {
            m.appendReplacement(sb, "<font color=\"#006600\">" + m.group(1) + "</font>");
        }
        m.appendTail(sb);
```

I also tried using

```
    Pattern linkPattern = Pattern.compile("(http[A-Za-z0-9_-+)");
```

But couldn't insert : or // in the [].

Comment: you pattern is of, it lacks at least a closing ] (and :, and / and . It cannot even match the link you showed.)

Comment: I meant the : after http and // after the :. NVM i found the answwer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this for your second method.

```
    Pattern linkPattern = Pattern.compile("(http://t.co/[A-Za-z0-9_-]+)");
```

It will compile after the `t.co/` so it won't face symbols or anything but letter and numbers.

Comment: @JohnJared add s? after http (meaning character s, 0 or 1 time)

Comment: Just create another pattern with an s after the http. Then use it, it is not that much efficient, but it will get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add following attributes to your TextView in xml

```
android:autoLink="web"
android:textColorLink="your-color-code"
```

Comment: It is not about coloring only, I would like to save the link for further things. So I can't use this method.